# LibGDX Ansichtsfenster - Viewports

Tags: android, libgdx

I just can't get any further.
Made a simple game with LibGDX.
Scene 2D with uiStage and mainStage. I just can't get the black bars to be displayed with different Android resolutions.
It's still best with ExtendViewport. But even there I have a black bar on the right or above.
My background image is the same size as the viewport setting.
No bar can be seen with the Android emulators, but with e.g. Samsung cell phones (high resolution) it is.

LibGDX quote:
Here is an example use of ExtendViewport. The 640 x 480 stage size is first scaled to fit without changing the aspect ratio. It then expands the shorter size of the stage to fill the screen. The aspect ratio is not changed and there are no black bars, but the stage can be longer in one direction.
Quote end

I have now read what feels like hundreds of answers to this question on the internet. But without success.
I don't quite understand that with the world coordinates either.
It must be possible with viewports that no black bars are displayed?
Would be grateful for any help...

My code:

```
public BaseScreen()
{



    assMan.loadAll();
    assMan.manager.finishLoading();


    mainStage = new Stage(viewport=new ExtendViewport(550,850));
    uiStage = new Stage(viewport1=new ExtendViewport(550,850));




    initialize();
}



//RESIZE METHODE:
```

public void resize(int width, int height) {

```
    mainStage.getViewport().update(width, height);
    uiStage.getViewport().update(width, height);


}
```

Das funktioniert auch nicht:

int breite=Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
int hoehe=Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();

```
    mainStage = new Stage(viewport=new ExtendViewport(550,850 *(hoehe/breite)));
    uiStage = new Stage(viewport=new ExtendViewport(550,850));
```

[image]

Comment: ExtendViewport is correct. It looks like the problem is in the Android configuration. It’s reserving room for the status bar.

Comment: No. I don't think space is reserved for the status bar. The place would be too big. Also, if I change the width of the background, then the height fits again without red bars. But if I set the width and height like this (e.g. 16:9) then it no longer fits with other resolutions.
I just can't bring it.